# Grails Domain Rest service only returning 10 rows

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, grails

The Problem: When using @Resource on the domain to expose it to a rest call, I am only getting 10 rows returned. Why is this when the table has 20 rows ? This is an existing table mapped to the domain.

Testing: Using Curl or web browser I get only 10 rows returned. When I have SQL logging turned on it is putting a TOP 10 ? in the query ?

SQL logs:

Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from zt6 this_
Hibernate: select top 10 this_.id as id1_1_0_, this_.description as descript2_1_0_ from zt6 this_

Why the top 10 ??

When I test with the grails console I get all the rows:

println Dcmnetwork.count()

Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from zt6 this_
20

The domain is:

```
package testrest

import grails.rest.*

@Resource(uri='/test' )
class Dcmnetwork{

    int id
    String Description

    static mapping = {
        table 'zt6'
        version false
        id column: "id"
        cache 'read-only'
    }
    static constraints = {}
}
```

Output of web browser:

```
<list>
<dcmnetwork id="1">
<description>Self Test</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="2">
<description>Test 2</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="3">
<description>Test 3</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="4">
<description>Test 4</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="5">
<description>Test 5</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="6">
<description>Test 6</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="7">
<description>Test 7</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="8">
<description>Test 8</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="9">
<description>Test 9</description>
</dcmnetwork>
<dcmnetwork id="10">
<description>Test10</description>
</dcmnetwork>
</list>
```

Comment: Can you try adding either `max=20` or `offset=10` parameter to your query and see if anything changes? It looks like the auto-generated controller is paging the results.

Answer (score 0):

First of all find out which controller is responsible for this output

```
grails url-mapping-report
```

Then override getter with your needs:

```
class DcmnetworkController extends RestfulController<Metric> {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    DcmnetworkController() {
        super(Dcmnetwork)
    }

    @Override
    def index() {
        respond Dcmnetwork.list()
    }
}
```